# Two custom framework using same framwork inside them, after using them in Application cause issue, One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have framework 'A' and framework 'B', this both framework use framework 'C' inside it. Also I have one DemoApp for testing. I have use 'A.framework' and 'B.framework' inside my DemoApp.
DemoApp is build successfully, but while running it throw following error.

Class SomeCodes is implemented in both /Users/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/C.framework/ and /Users/DemoApp.app/DemoApp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

This issue is not related to cocoapods integration inside frameworks. I have create custom frameworks and use them.

Someone could help me?

Comment: Does it actually throw an error and crash or is it a warning in the console? The solution to this is to not build the frameworks yourself manually and instead use Swift Package Manager or Cocoapods or Carthage. This is exactly the type of thing they were built to avoid, they manage dependencies and ensure everything is installed and only installed once

Comment: Yes its actually crashing on app side. I don’t wants to create cocoapods. Is there any other way like exclude the dependency framework while building the main framework.